# Git pass gitignore file as command line argument

Tags: git, arguments, gitignore

Is there a way to pass the path to a different gitignore file (or pipe the content of a gitignore file) to git commands?

Basically I want to do `git diff --no-index path1 path2` but I want git to ignore some files, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify files to exclude as part of the `git diff` command line.  You can, however, list up all the files that you want to diff.  The first technique would be to use wildcards, like:

```
  git diff --no-index dir1/*/dir2/*.h
```

Another option is to use `xargs` to create the files for `git diff`, as:

```
ls <whatever matches> | xargs git diff --no-index --
```

Of course, in the above, something more than `ls` is probably needed.